# How many integers contain a number in a specific range

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

The program should take input the number, the start of the range and the end of the range, and output how many integers the number appears between the start and end of the range, **inclusive**. Both programs and functions are allowed.

### Example Inputs

For example:

```
//Input example 1
3,1,100
//Input example 2
3
1
100
//Input example 3
3 1 100
//Input example 4
a(3, 1, 100);
```

All the above four input examples are valid and all of them mean that `3` is the number in question, `1` is the beginning of the range and `100` the the end of the range.

And then the program should output how many times `3` appears in the range from `1` to `100` **inclusive**. `3` appears in the integers `3`, `13`, `23`, `30`, `31`, `32`, `33`, ..., `93` at a total of 19 times. So the program should output `19` as the output because that is how many times `3` appears in the range from `1` to `100`.

### Rules

- Both programs and functions are allowed.
- All numbers will be integers, meaning that there will **not** be any `float`s or `double`s.
- Note: the sought number will always be in the range `0≤x≤127`. There will be **no** cases where it will be outside this `0≤x≤127` range.
- As in the first example, with the case as `33`, the number `3` will be counted as appearing only **once**, **not** twice.
- The values of the start and end of the range will be between `-65536` and `65535` inclusive.
- The value of range's start will never exceed or equal to range's end. `start < end`
- Also the range is inclusive. For example if the input was `8 8 10`, the range would be `8≤x≤10` and hence the output will be 1.
- Input can be taken in any of the ways shown in the examples. Input can be taken as a string or as a number, any way you wish.

### Test Cases

```
3 1 100
19

3 3 93
19

12,-200,200
24          //This is because 12 appears in -129, -128, ..., -112, -12, 12, 112, 120, 121, 122, ...

123,1,3
0           //This is because all of 123's digits have to appear in the same order

3 33 34
2           //Because 3 appears in 2 numbers: 33 and 34

a(0,-1,1);
1

$ java NotVerbose 127 -12 27
0
```

## Snack Snippet

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 98470; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 41805; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Input in the form: **upper bound**, **lower bound**, **number**.

```
Ÿvy³åO
```

Explanation:

```
Ÿ       # Inclusive range, [a, ..., b]
 vy     # For each element...
   ³å   # Check if the third input is a substring of the number
     O  # Sum up the results
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xbh2ecKzw6VP&input=MjAwCi0yMDAKMTI)

Comment: *Chooses Groovy* `{a,b,c->}` Aww... dangit, I lost before I started again.

Comment: Congrats for winning this challenge!

Comment: @KritixiLithos Thank you! :)

Comment: 6-bytes alternative: [`Ÿʒ³å}g`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6I5Tkw5tPry0Nv3/fyMDAy5dEGFoBAA)

Answer (score 10):

## Bash, 20 bytes

the obvious answer

```
seq $2 $3|grep -c $1
```

example

```
$ bash golf 3 1 100
19
```

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 20 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes by using `grep` as in @ardnew's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98490/55508).*

Bytecount includes 18 bytes of code and `-ap` flags.

```pl
$_=grep/@F/,<>..<>
```

Give the 3 numbers on three separate lines :

```
perl -ape '$_=grep/@F/,<>..<>' <<< "3
1
100"
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>47</s> 43 Bytes

Relatively straightforward, making use of Python 2's `repr` short-form.

```python
f=lambda n,a,b:a<b and(`n`in`a`)+f(n,-~a,b)
```

Ouput:

```python
f(  3,    1, 100) -> 19
f(  3,    3,  93) -> 19
f( 12, -200, 200) -> 24
f(123,    1,   3) -> 0
f(  3,   33,  34) -> 2
f(  0,   -1,   1) -> 1
f(127,   12,  27) -> 0
```

Comment: Why did you have to be all fancy and use `-~a` instead of `a+1`?

Comment: @Artyer for fun!

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)! (Use `w` and filtering to avoiding `@`.)

```
rAwƇ⁵L
```

**[TryItOnline!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/IsfxY@6PGrT7////XNTIw@A/ChkYA)**

Input: Start, End, ToFind

#### How?

```
rAwƇ⁵L - Main link: Start, End, ToFind
r      - range: [Start, ..., End]
 A     - absolute values
    ⁵  - third input: ToFind
   Ƈ   - filter keep those (absolute values, a) for which:
  w    -   first index of sublist (implicit digits of ToFind) in (implicit digits of a)
     L - length
```

The default casting of an integer to an iterable for the sublist existence check casts to a decimal list (not a character list), so negative numbers have a leading negative value (e.g. `-122`->`[-1,2,2]` which won't find a sublist of `[1,2]`) so taking the absolute value first seems like the golfiest solution.

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/79I37H8WLvP/8PLlSL//4821FEwNDCI1VGINtZRsDQGMXSNDAx0jCCCQGmwmDFQ1tgELAvSAWEY6SgYmcf@B0kBxYxAGMI2ADHNAQ)

Comment: Thanks @cairdcoinheringaahing that's great, I went with something closer to the original.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
f=(n,s,e)=>s<=e&&!!`${s++}`.match(n)+f(n,s,e)
```

(My best nonrecursive version was 61 bytes.) Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @edc65.

Comment: `!!match` instead of `includes`.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>64</s> <s>62</s> 56 bytes

```
param($c,$a,$b)$(for(;$a-le$b){1|?{$a++-match$c}}).count
```

*-6 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Input via command-line arguments of the form **number lower_bound upper_bound**. A little goofy on the notation, because of the semicolons inside the `for` causing parse errors if it's not surrounded in `$(...)` to create a script block. We basically loop upward through `$a` until we hit `$b`, using `Where-Object` (the `|?{...}`) to pull out those numbers that regex `-match` against `$c`. That's encapsulated in parens, we take the `.count` thereof, and that's left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

---

If, however, we guarantee that the range will be no more than 50,000 elements, we can skip the loop and just use the range operator `..` directly, for **<s>45</s> 43 bytes**. Since that's not in the challenge specifications, though, this isn't valid. Bummer.

```
param($c,$a,$b)($a..$b|?{$_-match$c}).count
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for 50K elements info. A couple of suggestions `param($c,$a,$b)$(for(;$a-le$b){1|?{$a++-match$c}}).count`

Comment: The `param($c,$a,$b)($a..$b|?{$_-match$c}).count` works with range -65536..65535 on `Powershell 5.1`

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, <s>46</s>, 41 bytes

```
C<C-r>=r<tab><C-r>")<cr><esc>jC0<esc>:g/<C-r>"/norm G<C-v><C-a>
kd{
```

Input is in this format:

```
1, 100
3
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 65 bytes

```
import Data.List
(s#e)i=sum[1|x<-[s..e],isInfixOf(show i)$show x]
```

The `import` ruins the score. Usage example: `((-200)#200)12` -> `24`.

Comment: The usage example should output 24 because 12 appears 24 times between -200 and 200

Comment: @KritixiLithos: Oh sorry! It does of course, it's just a copy & pase error.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7 85 bytes

```java
int x(int a,int b,int c){int t=0;for(;b<=c;)if((b+++"").contains(a+""))t++;return t;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 3, <s>96</s> 93 bytes

```
import Cocoa
func c(n:Int,s:Int,e:Int){print((s...e).filter{"\($0)".contains("\(n)")}.count)}
```

**Edit 1:**

Saved 3 bytes by using shorthand parameters

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 50 bytes

```
(c:String)=>(_:Int)to(_:Int)count(""+_ contains c)
```

takes the first input curried; call it like this: `f("12")(-200,200)`

Explantion:

```
(c:String)=>  //define an anonymous function taking a string parameter
  (_:Int)     //create a range from an anonymous int parameter
  to          //to
  (_:Int)     //another anonymous int parameter
  count(      //and count how many...
   ""+_       //elements converted to a string
   contains c //contain c
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 32 bytes

Quite straightforward:

```
function(a,b,c)sum(grepl(a,b:c))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice answer but assuming that input is already specified is generally not accepted. To make your answer qualify you would either have to read input from stdin such as: `a=scan();sum(grepl(a,a[2]:a[3]))` or as arguments to a function: `function(a,b,c)sum(grepl(a,b:c))`, both equivalent in this case.

Comment: @Billywob thanks, will keep this in mind! edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
f=(i,s,e)=>s>e?0:RegExp(i).test(s)+f(i,++s,e)
```

Recursively count until start > end

Edit: Switch to RegExp test to save a byte

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>68</s> 63 bytes

```
for($a=$argv;$a[2]<=$a[3];)$o+=strstr($a[2]++,$a[1])>'';echo$o;
```

use like:

```
 php -r "for($a=$argv;$a[2]<=$a[3];)$o+=strstr($a[2]++,$a[1])>'';echo$o;" 3 1 100
```

edit: 5 bytes saved thanks to Titus

Comment: `strstr($a[2]++,$a[1])>""` instead of `strpos($a[2]++,$a[1])!==false` saves 5 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 71 bytes

Beat my Java answer thanks to lambdas

```
(t,l,u)=>{int d=0;for(;l<=u;)if((l+++"").Contains(t+""))d++;return d;};
```

Comment: Java also has lambdas

Comment: Yeah I just started reading about it, but don't they require some boilerplate stuff that would make the bytecount larger, or can I not count it

Comment: Shamelessly stole @Grax s javascript answer `(n,s,e)=>s>e?0:((""+s).Contains(n+"")?1:0)+f(n,++s,e);` is way shorter

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 44 bytes

```ruby
m=->(n,s,f){(s..f).count{|x|x.to_s[/#{n}/]}}
```

Test Cases:

```ruby
m.(3,1,100)     #=> 19
m.(3,3,93)      #=> 19
m.(12,-200,200) #=> 24
m.(123,1,3)     #=>  0
m.(3,33,34)     #=>  2
m.(0,-1,1)      #=>  1
m.(127,-12,27)  #=>  0
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>143</s> 135 bytes

Thanks to @Kritixi Lithos for helping save 8 bytes

Surely this can be done better, but its the best I've got for now.  C doesn't handle strings very gracefully, so naturally it takes quite a few operations.

```
int C(int N,int l,int h){char b[99],n[99];int t=0,i=1;sprintf(n,"%d",N);for(;i<=h;i++){sprintf(b,"%d",i);if(strstr(b,n))++t;}return t;}
```

**Ungolfed + program**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int C(int N,int l,int h)
{
    char b[99], n[99];
    int t=0,i=1;
    sprintf(n,"%d",N);
    for(;i<=h;i++)
    {
        sprintf(b,"%d",i);
        if(strstr(b,n))
            ++t;
    }
    return t;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", C(3, 1, 100));
}
```

Comment: I think you can remove the `int i=l` from the for-loop and instead initialise it with `int t=0` like such `int t=0,i=l` to save a few bytes.

Comment: This not compile?  C( N, l, h){char b[99], n[99];int t=0,i=l;sprintf(n,"%d",N);for(;i<=h;i++){sprintf(b,"%d",i);if(strstr(b,n))++t;}return t;} I think compile even with no include...

Comment: 93 bytes `b[9],n[9],t;C(N,l,h){for(t=!sprintf(n,"%d",N);l<=h;strstr(b,n)&&++t)sprintf(b,"%d",l++);N=t;}`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 62 bytes

Pretty straight forward approach:

```
<?=count(preg_grep('/'.($a=$argv)[1].'/',range($a[2],$a[3])));
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/3BBoO)

Comment: Save 4 bytes with underscore or any letter as regex delimiter. (needs no quotes)

Comment: You can save 3 Byte `<?=count(preg_grep("/$argv[1]/",range($argv[2],$argv[3])));`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 8 bytes

Takes the integer to be found as the last input value.

```
õV èÈsøW
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9VYg6Mhz+Fc=&input=LTIwMCwyMDAsMTI=)

---

### Explanation

```
             :Implicit input of integers U=start, V=end & W=number
õV           :Range [U,V]
    È        :Map
     s       :  Convert to string
      øW     :  Contains W?
   è         :Count truthy values
```

Comment: Since the previous versions lack an explanation I'm not sure about those, but your current 6-byte solution is incorrect I'm afraid. See this rule: "_As in the first example, with the case as `33`, the number `3` will be counted as appearing only once, not twice._" Your occurrence-count for `W` would count the `3` twice.

Comment: Thanks, @KevinCruijssen, came back to it ~a month later and was wondering why I was doing it the way I was when there was a shorter way - should have reread the challenge before updating! I've rolled it back now.

Comment: I had the same thing happen a few times. I see my answer, think: this can be much easier, am changing it. And right before I hit save changes I see I now misinterpret the challenge. Btw, I'm still curious about the explanation for the 8-byte solution. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 48 bytes

According to the rule, the range can contain more than 50,000 elements. So we can't use the range operator `..` directly. Thanks [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98478/80745).

Straightforward:

```powershell
param($c,$a,$b)for(;$a-le$b){$i+=$a++-match$c}$i
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($c,$a,$b)for(;$a-le$b){$i+=$a++-match$c}$i

}

@(
    ,(19, 3,1,100)
    ,(19, 3,3,93)
    ,(24, 12,-200,200)
    ,(0, 123,1,3)
    ,(2, 3,33,34)
    ,(1, 0,-1,1)
    ,(0, 127,-12,27)
    ,(44175, 0,-65536,65535)
) | % {
    $e,$a = $_
    $r = &$f @a
    "$($e-eq$r): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 19
True: 19
True: 24
True: 0
True: 2
True: 1
True: 0
True: 44175
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 7 bytes

```
÷ṡƛS?hc
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C3%B7%E1%B9%A1%C6%9BS%3Fhc&inputs=%5B3%2C1%2C100%5D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>92</s> <s>89</s> 71 bytes

Now with lambdas!

```
(t,l,u)->{int z=0;for(;l<=u;)if((l+++"").contains(t+""))z++;return z;};
```

Old 89 byte function solution:

```
int d(int t,int l,int u){int a=0,i=l;for(;i<=u;)if((i+++"").contains(t+""))a++;return a;}
```

Hooray for the super increment function!

Comment: You can remove `int i=l` from the for-loop and instead declare it with `a` like `int a=0,i=l;` to save few bytes

Comment: Ah I knew I missed something, thanks!

Comment: Basically the same as this [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98484/41805).

Answer (score 0):

### [GolfSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/GolfSharp), 41 bytes

```
(w,q,e)=>r(q,1+e-q).w(n=>n.T().I(w)).L();
```

#### A 45 byte version:

---

```
(w,q,e)=>r(q,1+e-q).w(n=>n.T().I(w.T())).L();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 48 bytes

```
{a,b,c->(a..b).collect{"$it".count("$c")}.sum()}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 91 bytes

```
(for/sum((i(range s(+ 1 e))))(if(string-contains?(number->string i)(number->string d))1 0))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f d s e)
  (for/sum ((i (range s (+ 1 e))))
    (if(string-contains?
        (number->string i)
        (number->string d))
       1 0 )))
```

Testing:

```
(f 3 1 100)
(f 3 3 93)
(f 12 -200 200)
(f 123 1 3)
(f 3 33 34)
(f 0 -1 1)
```

Output:

```
19
19
24
0
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom bytes 90

```
f(y,a,b)==(c:=0;for x in a..b repeat(if position(y::String,x::String,1)~=0 then c:=c+1);c)
```

results

```
(3) -> f(3,1,100)=19,f(3,3,93)=19,f(12,-200,200)=24,f(123,1,3)=0,f(3,33,34)=2
   (3)  [19= 19,19= 19,24= 24,0= 0,2= 2]
                                  Type: Tuple Equation NonNegativeInteger
(4) -> f(0,-1,1)=1, f(127,12,27)=0
   (4)  [1= 1,0= 0]
                                  Type: Tuple Equation NonNegativeInteger
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
(w=ToString;t=0;Table[If[StringContainsQ[w@i,w@#1],t++],{i,#2,#3}];t)&
```

**input**

> [12,-200,200]

**output**

> 24

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 65 bytes

```
#(count(for[i(range %2(inc %3)):when(some(set(str %))(str i))]i))
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 56 Bytes

run as pipe
[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoMClkliUXqZgqxBtrGOoY2hgEGvNZW8HlLQtLk0qLimKT84vzSvRyMrPzNMoSsxLT9XQUEm0BWvSjDaM1VFJjDaK1dQE0Qaxmtb//wMA)

**Input**

```
$argv = [number_to_find, range_start, range_end];
```

**Code**

```
<?=substr_count(join(range(($a=$argv)[1],$a[2])),$a[0]);
```

**Explanation**

```
#substrcount, counts the aparitions of a subtring in a string
substr_count( 
           join( range(($a=$argv)[1],$a[2])), # String with the range
           $a[0]);                            # The number you are looking for
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32 bytes

```perl6
{+grep *.contains($^a),$^b..$^c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1o7vSi1QEFLLzk/ryQxM69YQyUuUVNHJS5JT08lLrn2f3FipUKahrGOgiEQGRho/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `rs`, 5 bytes

```
_ṡ?vc  # main program
```

```
_      # discard the initial number
 ṡ     # inclusive range over implicit inputs
  ?    # number to be checked
   vc  # vectorized contains, sum the list
```

I had to use -r because v vectorizes the first part of the stack otherwise (?)

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rs&code=_%E1%B9%A1%3Fvc&inputs=3%0A1%0A100&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
IƝc
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUklQzYlOURjJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9LTIwMCUwQTIwMCUwQTEyJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
IƝc  # Implicit input
I    # Inclusive range between the first two inputs
 Ɲ   # Join it on newlines
  c  # Count occurrences of the third input
     # Implicit output
```