# How many 1's we get

Tags: code-golf, number

### Description

Count how many occurrences there are of the digit **1** between two given numbers \$[a, b]\$, inclusive.

For example, from 1 to 100 it should be 21:

**1**, **1**0,  **11**,  **1**2, **1**3, **1**4, **1**5, **1**6, **1**7, **1**8, **1**9, 2**1**, 3**1**, 4**1**, 5**1**, 6**1**, 7**1**, 8**1**, 9**1**, **1**00

The number **1** is repeated 21 times.

### Rules

1. Each number in the input list is guaranteed is an integer in the range \$0 \leq a \leq b < 2^{32}\$.
2. The shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[1, 100] -> 21
[11, 200] -> 138
[123, 678] -> 182
```

### Example

Here is my code using bash

```
eval echo {$1..$2}|grep -o 1|wc -l
```

Comment: https://oeis.org/A094798

Comment: Have we not had this before? I have recollections of something using a fixed range, no input that, possibly, asked us to count `2`s instead of `1`s.

Comment: @Shaggy maybe [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166199/count-ones-in-range) is what you're thinking of?

Comment: @Giuseppe, close, yeah. But the one I'm thinking of definitely took no input and used decimal, not binary. Obviously, it was a terrible challenge but, if I can find it, it's a definite dupe target. It's also extremely likely that my stupid broken brain is lying to me and no such challenge exists!

Comment: @Shaggy I also definitely remember that challenge.

Comment: are we to assume base-10 only?

Comment: @Shaggy maybe [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98470/how-many-integers-contain-a-number-in-a-specific-range?rq=1) then? Not quite the same, but you did write an [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122054/67312) in Japt, so I know you were aware of it at some point!

Comment: Is the `eval` needed in your example?

Comment: you can also directly use ```grep -c 1``` instead of ```grep -o 1| wc -l```.

Comment: @NordineLotfi, `grep -c 1` only counts 11 once, not twice, as the challenge requires

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

Thanks a lot to OP! Now I can save a byte

```
ŸSΘO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6I7gczP8//@PNtQxNDCIBQA)

### Explanation

```
Ÿ    Inclusive range
 S   Split the string into individual chars
  Θ  (Vectorizes) Does this character == "1"?
   O Sum the resulting list
```

Comment: I had the same in mind, but you beat me to it. A minor alternative is `SΘO` instead of `J1¢`. :)

Comment: You didn't had to change your original approach. The `J1¢` is just as valid as `SΘO`. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well, I read "a minor alternative" as "the way to make my answer more idiomatic"...

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>39</s></sup> 36 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @SurculoseSputum

```python
lambda a,b:`range(a,b+1)`.count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7RqsIwDIbv@xRBGGs4cdgKOoSdJzkXduq0sLWlrRc@/Uw7Ti5C/vD9fxI@@eWdXicY4G@dzTLeDRgaL9do3PMhefxReO1u/u2ybFWLq12CjxnSJwkx@QizdQ@wriy6lO/WXQRwWRcI/DtzcCG6mHK0QWKXwmw5Cva/0GJFDcHI2GKCtC5Tsf5T1CKKCj19iZpkgTdbbSGyRe6aBMMA3GWTcAcNSObrfdqcAxSONSKuitThUB7QSihFehPq2Aulj3Q691X2@gs)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>42</s></sup> 40 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @JoKing

```python
lambda a,b:f"{*range(a,b),b}".count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BisMwDETv/goRCLGKGuoEdkMh/ZK9ONuma0hsY7uHUvrtqeywOgyMeDOSf6Y/Z/tthhF@tkWv01WDpuk8V69D0PZ@k@yQpnfV/rqHTbJRDW5m9S4kiM8oxOwCLMbewNi8aGO6GnsWwGOsJ3CPxOWZaENMwXiJbfSL4So4XqDBgmqCibFVe2lsohz9p6hBFAW6u1w1ywzvsSI@cERWdYRxBFZZR6ygBsl8uU97coTMsUfETZE6nfIDnRJKUbcb1Q9CdT19fQ/FDt0H)

Comment: In the Python 2 version, you can use back tick `\`range(a,b+1)\`` to save 3 bytes

Answer (score 7):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)+[itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools), 42 bytes

```rust
|a,b|(a..=b).join("").matches('1').count()
```

[Try it in the Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddd5ae6f71aee1a0d4392a066410fe24)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 bytes

```apl
+/'1'=⍕⍤…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X1tf3VDd9lHv1Ee9Sx41LPuf9qhtwqPevkddzY961zzq3XJovfGjtomP@qYGBzkDyRAPz@D/hgppCoYGBlyGIIYRiGFkDGSZmVsAAA)

`+/` sum

`'1'=` where the character is equal to

`⍕` the string representation

`⍤` of

`…` the range

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, <s>71</s> <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```java
a->b->{var s="";for(;b>=a;)s+=b--;return~-s.split("1",-1).length;}
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY8xb4MwEIX3/IqTJyxsK06ltooLY6UOnTIiBkOAmjoG4SMlQvSvUyeNOnf77t7du3etPmveHj/X0mrv4V0bN28APGo0JbRBFSMaK@rRlWg6J17v8PLmsGqqgf1v6A5pCjUkq@ZpwdP5rAfwCSGq7oZIFWmiFfVxUnCuhgrHwX1zL3xvDUZEEsYlFbZyDX6oZVWbELMfCxti3tOeO3OEU/ggOuBgXJPloOn1G4DrAeMwdCbYg6u@4FZl@TxLJrfbhc1Sst0v7B7Y49PzstDbKsDh4rE6iW5E0QdftC6asm0eE0biKZMB9kDiWui@t5ebRP9Y5pSq4LNslvUH)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->{                // Method with two integer inputs and integer return-type
  var s="";            //  String `s`, starting empty
  for(;b>=a;)          //  Loop `b` downwards in the range [`b`, `a`]:
    s+=b--;            //   And append `b` to to String `s`
  return~-s.split("1", //  Split String `s` on "1",
                  -1)  //  and keep empty trailing items
           .length;    //  Then get the amount of parts of this array
                       //  And decrease it by 1 with `~-`, before turning it as result
```

Comment: Nice use of the `-->` operator ;-)

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY8xb4MwEIX3/IqTJyxsK06lNooLY6UOnTIiBkMgdeoYhI@UCPHbqUNR527f3bt79@6ib5pfTl9zabX38KGNGzcAHjWaEi5BFT0aK@relWgaJ95WeH13WJ2rjv1vaIU0hRqSWfO04Ol40x34hBBVN12kijTRivo4KThXXYV958AL31qDEZGEcUmFrdwZP7lU06w2IWfbFzbkXOPeGnOCa3ghOmJn3DnLQdPHOwCPC8Zh6AxwAFd9w1Jl@ThKJrfbiY1Sst0v7J7Y88t@muiyCnC8e6yuoulRtMEXrYuGbJvHhJF4yGSAA5C4Frpt7X2R6B/LnFIVfKbNNP8A)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! And 1 more byte by using `~-` instead of `-1` to get rid of the space. :)

Comment: 3 different forms of writing `-1` in one answer? I approve! 

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <sup><s>29</s> <s>28</s></sup> 27 bytes

```matlab
@(x,y)sum(mat2str(x:y)==49)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KnUrO4NFcjN7HEqLikSKPCqlLT1tbEUvN/moahjqGBgSYXkGGoYwRlGRnrmJlbaP4HAA)

Comment: You can remove the square brackets. Also, does `48` work instead of `"1"`?

Comment: Luis probably meant 49, since 48 is zero?

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
function(x,y)sum(unlist(gregexpr(1,x:y))>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfnF@aVxKfn5dabPs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqdSs7g0V6M0LyezuEQjvSg1PbWioEjDUKfCqlJT085AE0kfUNTQwECTC1nEUMcIXcjIWMfM3ELzPwA)

Comment: Nice! I had [this](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJs7g0VyMvOSOxSCO9uDRJQyk6zjBWSUdJSSfRKklTU/N/moahjqGBgeZ/AA) at 44; regex were definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>62</strike> <strike>46</strike> 28 bytes

```ruby
->c,d{[*c..d].join.count ?1}
```

-18 bytes, courtesy of [Dingus.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5ZJ6U6WitZTy8lVi8rPzNPLzm/NK9Ewd6w9n@BQlq0oY6hgUEsF5hpqGMEZxsZ65iZW8T@BwA)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5ZJ6U6WitZTy8lVi8rPzNPLzm/NK9Ewd6w9n@BQlq0oY6hgUEsF5hpqGMEZxsZ65iZW8T@BwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
\d+
$*_
(?<=(_+) _*)(?=\1)
$.'
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFK55Lw97GViNeW1MhXktTw942xlCTS0VPncvw/39DBUMDAy5DQwUjEGVkrGBmbgEA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*_
```

Convert `a` and `b` to unary, but use `_` instead of `1` to avoid confusion. (In Retina 1 this would just be `*`, saving 2 bytes.)

```
(?<=(_+) _*)(?=\1)
$.'
```

At each boundary in `b` up to and including `a` from the end, insert the distance to the end in decimal, thus generating the range from `b` down to `a`.

```
1
```

Count the resulting number of `1`s.

Comment: Out of curiosity: if it's shorter in Retina instead of Retina 0.8.2, why not just post that version instead? At least, that's what I usually do with 05AB1E / 05AB1E (legacy) / 2sable. Sometimes bytes can be saved by switching the language to a previous or later version.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I prefer to answer in Retina 0.8.2 if it's reasonably possible, only using Retina when I need a few feature, e.g. randomness.

Comment: Ah ok. Is there a reason why you prefer to answer in 0.8.2? Tbh, I was the same a few years back with only answering in Java 7, even though Java 8 with lambdas was always shorter, so I can definitely relate. :)

Comment: Maybe I'm just trying to show off how well I can golf by deliberately using an "inferior" language? (Having said that, I've just golfed off 4 bytes...)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>g=b=>b<a?0:(b+g).split(1).length-3+g(b-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XclBDsIgEADAu6/guJsGykKipJH6FqgUawg0Qvw@etBL5zpP93Z1eW1747ncQ19td3aO1tvZX91NTuCHiKLuaWtAKFLIsT24HiJ4TtiXkmtJQaQSYQXGCIGkRGTjyBSdDk3fVv8mbQ5PSiOcL@b3RvUP)

#### How?

We use a recursive function `g` to count how many `1`'s we have in `b` and decrement `b` until it's lower than `a`.

In order to count the `1`'s, we have to coerce `b` to a string. We could do `b+''` but it's shorter to use `b+g`. Because the source code of `g` itself contains two `1`'s, we subtract `3` instead of just `1` from the result of `(b+g).split(1).length`.

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets, 68

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(""&SEQUENCE(A2-A1+1,1,A1),"[^1]",
```

Sheets auto-closes parens.

This is super slow at large ranges, but as this is Code Golf, we're here to optimize character count. My first attempt was to use `JOIN(SEQUENCE(...))` to make one long string then count the 1's, but as it turns out, Sheets has a limit of 50000 characters, so that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 49 bytes

```
{x:Int,y:Int->(x..y).sumBy{"$it".count{it=='1'}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcnBCoMgGADgu0/xE4MUytJgi4EddttjxECQ2V9sOhLx2V2jHbp8l@85O2swa48wjQYpg0g@owUNKsf1ekdXhZ/1QFfOA@NvP91CLE7GFfwxe3TROKVKUaaU8vIy6CxSTUUFom0ZA4CmgXoAKchht5Z77yu6/tiyq@B86bf/dy9JyvkL)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
a!b=sum[1|'1'<-show[a..b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1Exyba4NDfasEbdUN1Gtzgjvzw6UU8vKTb2f25iZp6CrUJKvkJBUWZeiYahoqGBgaY1jGeoaITMNTJWNDO30PwPAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
↨æ▒m┴Σ]Σ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9R24rDyx5Nm5T7aMqWc4tjzy3@/99Qx9DAgMvQUMcIRBkZ65iZWwAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
↨         # Loop in the range [a,b] using the two implicit inputs a,b,
 æ        # and execute the following four commands:
  ▒       #  Convert the integer to a list of digits
   m      #  Map over each digit:
    ┴     #   And check which are equal to 1 (1 if 1; 0 otherwise)
     Σ    #  Get the sum of those checks
      ]   # After the loop, wrap all values on the stack into a list
       Σ  # And sum this list
          # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>46</del> 45 bytes

```php
fn($a,$b)=>substr_count(join(range($a,$b)),1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1PC4IwGMbv@xQvsoODiW5CCaadgg5B3lViiss6OHHzFH329RJC3R5@z795nP3hOI8zIVQXXk8hVZx2rCjt2lm33HqzTi58mscULmq6D5vPuGA@x5IbrLNQQE1qwUEkScshjiEqQQpEyOQfE2mGUKYcdvvsRzNJWhzTZhlUP4awrSqLChi8CECNv0C7Fq@oyxEM/WggoCqiXeOisnEB@hq73xwwDtW5up2ul5y8/Qc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 21 bytes

```perl
map$\+=y/1//,$_..<>}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlRtu2Ut9QX19HJV5Pz8autvr/f0NDLiMDg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Comment: 20 bytes: `$\+=y/1//for$_..<>}{`

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 40 bytes

```powershell
$a,$b=$args
($a..$b|sls 1 -a|% m*).Count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyVRRyXJViWxKL2YS0MlUU9PJammOKdYwVBBN7FGVSFXS1PPOb80r@T///@G/w0NDAA)

---

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 40 bytes

```powershell
($args-join'..'|iex|sls 1 -a|% m*).Count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0MlsSi9WDcrPzNPXU9PvSYztaKmOKdYwVBBN7FGVSFXS1PPOb80r@T///@G/w0NDAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 58 bytes

```c
i;c;f(a,b){for(c=0;b/a;)for(i=a++;i;i/=10)c+=i%10==1;a=c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBboMwDL33KywkpKSkIoC6MWXZZdpXFDSFELYcRivggIb4dmYgdK3USHZiv@fnONGHL62nyQotKqJYQYfq3BAtuShCJegcWKmCQFhhQxlxqgNp/YhLGQkltRgnW3fwo2xN6G7YAa450Zm2@1SnHCQMEYNotjgZxT2hcATOGcSze3pObzimv5i@M@XCgiGeRZIUXRo7lv5WzR6aVcbL@o8461/e0Y4eg9s48bBiKcGJgMzqti5Nj3VcuOMrtPbXnCuy9aWhS@yvGQFBsLAprMNud1Wo5IZe8FzcwcUGFw9hg/B12keEFgnr//znLw0iFfFOfsnAL3M4vOEGxC8p@G1W4xMoBgWDloFh@Eoogm1yJzHuxukP)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 65 bytes

```
: f ( a b -- n ) [a,b] [ number>string [ 49 = ] count ] map sum ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc09D4IwGATgnV9xoyaWUDR@QHRVFhbjRBgKeUGjLdiPEH59rTFuzw1314nWDtrfrkV5zvAkregFKew9HoU2pH/WQvVkYOjtSLVBoyZr51E/lEUeFWWGyzAxKdTMuGETsZ6sz9BhAYEGjEFhiUqsmhoVlJMN6ZOxod@HvDngiBrt4MJcHS5HGCeRew6eJGEljjhH@me6xna3/9p/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{+/"1"=,/$x_!1+y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/6fZlWtra9kqGSro69SEa9oqF1Z@z9NT13DUMHQwMDa0FDBCEQZGSuYmVto/v8PAA)

**Explanation:**

Range generation is inefficient (i.e. generate range 0..Y and then drop from front, rather than generating range X..Y) but saves 2 bytes.

```
{+/"1"=,/$x_!1+y} / the solution
{               } / lambda taking implicit x & y args
             1+y  / add 1 to y
            !     / range 0..N
          x_      / drop (_) x items from front
         $        / convert to string
       ,/         / flatten 
   "1"=           / is string equal to "1"?
 +/               / sum
```

Comment: Not worth it's own answer, but 16 bytes is possible in [ngn/k](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpbX9/Q1tAgpiJe0VC7svZ/moKeuoahgqGBgbWhoYIRiDIyVjAzt9D8DwA).

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>19</s> 16 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Jonah!

```
1#.1=/&":[,-.&i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1DG311ZSsonV09dQy9f5rcilwpSZn5CsoKBgaGChoWFunaSoYQoWMECJQITNzC5iIkTFXakVmibo616MpPY@mNGBDa2CMCUBFTTB1a5BUTACKGxkCCYiCJhAT6BAIR0EBLjEFrHoLks4ZSAqm4LAfrn4GHkeiuwjZqVhca2hsgeRckHuNEO5FdzBWNxNwNLoe/E4n4HpsHrAwQvKAkTGQBEYrHh@Q6Ql0bf8B)

Comment: `1#.1=/&":[,-.&i.` for [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1DG311ZSsonV09dQy9f5rcilwpSZn5CsoKBgaGChoWFunaSoYQoWMECJQITNzC5iIkTFXakVmibo616MpPY@mNGBDa2CMCUBFTTB1a5BUTACKGxkCCYiCJhAT6BAIR0EBLjEFrHoLks4ZSAqm4LAfrn4GHkeiuwjZqVhca2hsgeRckHuNEO5FdzBWNxNwNLoe/E4n4HpsHrAwQvKAkTGQBEYrHh@Q6Ql0bf8B "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Jonah Thank you, yours is much better!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
a=>b=>([...Array(b-a+1)].map((_,i)=>i+a)+'').split(1).length-1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XcmxDoIwEADQ3a/oxl2QgyuJsrSJ32GMORCwplJSiIlfXx104a3vIS9ZuujmtZjCrU@DSWJsayyciegUo7yhLSRnvNBTZoDr3qGxLhfMswxpmb1bgZF8P43rveDUhWkJvicfRhhAKUbgqkJUZak07zbN39b/5rrZPOsa4XBsft/o9AE)

```js
[...Array(b-a+1)] // an array of length b-a+1
map((_,i)=>i+a)   // fill it with numbers from a to b
+''               // convert it to a string with each number separated by a comma
.split(1)         // split at each 1
.length-1         // count the chunks and subtract 1
```

-1 byte thanks to @Jo King

Comment: Nice first solution! You can take input curry'ed to [save a byte](https://tio.run/##XcmxDoIwEADQ3a/oxl2QgyuJsrSJ32GMORCwplJSiIlfXx104a3vIS9ZuujmtZjCrU@DSWJsayyciegUo7yhLSRnvNBTZoDr3qGxLhfMswxpmb1bgZF8P43rveDUhWkJvicfRhhAKUbgqkJUZak07zbN39b/5rrZPOsa4XBsft/o9AE)

Comment: @JoKing appreciate that. I was reluctant to post since there were so many great solutions.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

The spec contradicts itself as to whether the range should be inclusive or not. If it shouldn't then replace `õ` with `o`.

```
õ ¬è1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SCs6DE&input=MTAw)

Comment: You will need to add `V` after `õ` since the challenge now asks for inclusive range between a to b rather than inclusive range between 1 and a

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```rust
|a,b|(a..=b).map(|x|format!("{}",x).matches('1').count()).sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY29DoIwFIVneYrCwr1JbagmavxhZPMhCoIytBh6mxApz16BwcHlnOTLyXd6Zyk0hmnVGkA2RhuqLUHwipcelBC3EoVWb/CDb7peK4ohGaeEDwum6lVbSGWKouqcIUAU1mnAgJdoimbvYrsWZ1aYuyNwtv3UfE3c5mvnoB2xZl6s74/yGUMDksssw1nyA5Lv/shuzw/H04Km8AU)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
&:V1V=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X80qzDDMtvj/f0MjYy4zcwsA)

### Explanation

```
&:V1V=s
     =s  % Count occurrences
   1V    % of '1' in
  V      % string of
&:       % inclusive range of input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>8</s></sup> 7 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @FryAmTheEggman

```
/`}QE"1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xz@hNtBVyfD/f0MjYy4zc4t/@QUlmfl5xf91UwA)

### Explanation

```
/`}QE"1
  }QE     # Inclusive range on input
 `        # string of the range ([1, 2, 3] -> "[1, 2, 3]")
/    "1   # count ones
```

Comment: Since the list characters don't matter, you can just use backtick instead of `jk`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>29</s> 21 bytes

```scala
_.to(_)+""count(49==)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM2VkpqmkGaloOGZV6KjACQ0FWztQLSC7f94vZJ8jXhNbSWl5PzSvBINE0tbW83/BUWZeSU5eRppGoY6CoYGBpqaXLX/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 80 bytes

```java
a->b->IntStream.range(a,b+1).flatMap(i->(""+i).chars()).filter(x->x==49).count()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY8xb8IwEIX3/IoTk12wRaUuFY3HSkgwZaw6XILjOnVsy74gUMVvTw1lK9Od3nf37t2ARxQhaj8cvmc7xpAIhqLJiayTT5vqn9ZPviMb/EOYKWkcr6jqHOYMe7QefiqAOLXOdpAJqZRjsAcYC2MNJevNxydgMpnfRgHe7zfetp600Wn1QNkFb5SCHmq47cwoVCtU4c1fiITeaIardvnMZe@Q9hiZFYotFkvLZfeFKTNekHWkEzsJdarrl9dCwuSJ8bk8cTVuzpn0KMNEMpas5DzrJcbozqwY35v1mvNNGb9Ul/kX)

Doesn't need much of an explanation, but here's one anyways:

```java
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Long>> f = 
    a -> b-> 
      IntStream
        .range(a,b+1) //Create an IntStream going from a to b
        .flatMap(i -> //Map every int i in that stream
          (""+i)      //Make it a string
          .chars()    //Turn that string to an IntStream
        )    //Flatten that
        .filter(x -> x == 49)  //Keep all the '1's
        .count();              //Find out how many '1's there are
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
rDFċ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/Ixe1It@H///8NDf8bGRgAAA)

**Explanation:**

```
rDFċ1
r      range of the inputs
 DF    make decimal and flatten; list of all the digits in the range
   ċ1  count occurences of 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Tr@DigitCount[Range@##,10,1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6TIwSUzPbPEOb80ryQ6KDEvPdVBWVnH0EDHMFbtf0BRZl6JgkN6tCFQxCCWC8E31DFCFTAy1jEzt4j9/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 56 bytes

```
f(a,b)=>'1'.allMatches([for(;a<=b;a++)a].join()).length;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/P00jUSdJ09ZO3VBdLzEnxzexJDkjtVgjOi2/SMM60cY2yTpRW1szMVYvKz8zT0NTUy8nNS@9JMP6f24iiK9QzaWgUFCUmVeikaZhqGNoYKCpaY0sZKhjhCFmZKxjZm4BEqz9DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [<s>18</s> 14 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
÷|Ë¶‘○Øî9þæEƥ"
```

## Explanation

Unpacked:

```
+\${=1}((1=>):|c
```

Ungolfed:

```
+\ Fold with addition
  ${ Filter with block
    =1 Equals one
  }
  (
    (
      1=> Range [1, in]
    )
    :| c Join with no separator
  ) Implicit, can be removed
```

Strings automatically coerced into array context, output implicit

Comment: Hi, User:ZippyMagician!

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 44 bytes

```
|>:a%:1=&+&/&0
v&n;>~1+::{:})?!
>v,a^!?)0:-\
```

The wrong tool for the job, as ><> knows nothing about decimal notation.

Takes (b,a) on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 63 bytes

```lua
c,a,b=0,...for i=a,b do c=c+({('').gsub(i,1,0)})[2]end print(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/WSdRJ8nWQEdPTy8tv0gh0xbIVUjJV0i2TdbWqNZQV9fUSy8uTdLI1DHUMdCs1Yw2ik3NS1EoKMrMK9FI1vz//7@h4X8jAwMA)

Apparently, we can't use `...` as a range for `for`. What a shame.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
1NSTa\,b
```

Inclusive range of a and b, converts to string, find number of 1's.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/f0C84JDFGJ@k/kGn438jAAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
#1ṁd…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X9nw4c7GlEcNy/7//2/439DAAAA)

Jelly, but reversed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õV ¬è1
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9VYgrOgx&input=MTIzLDY3OA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 78 bytes

Just generates a range, and then counts the occurances of `1`'s.

```
method(a,b,Range 1 to(b)asList select(i,i>=a)join asList select(i,i=="1")size)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZckxDsIwDAXQnVN8dYolD3WRACGFEzAxs6TgglFJEPHE5QMTA6zvWWkTthHHdle/lnNIPPIh5YtC4CWMlOreqqPqrCcPxraLiW7FMv4mxk46qvZSalMQgKXvCY@nZZ/z4kMCHn5oWPJqvflSewM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
Ｉ№⪫…·ＮＮω1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sRhI5JcCmV75mXkannnJOaXFmWWpQYl56alAbkFpiV9pblJqkYamjgIKF8gvB2IlQyVNTU3r//8NFQwNDP7rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
      Ｎ     First input as a number
     Ｎ      Second input as a number
   …·       Inclusive range
  ⪫    ω    Cast to string and join
 №      1   Count literal `1`s
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 bytes

```
U$¦_1C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P1Tl0LJ4Q@f//w25DA0MAA)

```
U	| Inclusive range [a,b]
$¦_	| Flattened list of digits
1C	| Count 1s
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

```
uax#$'1ac
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/780sUJZRd0wMfn/f0MuQwMDAA)

### Explanation

```
uax#      Push the inclusive range
    $     Turn it into a string
     '1ac Count the amount of ones
```

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 65 bytes

```fs
fun x y->Seq.sumBy(fun a->a.ToString().Split("1").Length-1){x..y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pcyxCsIwFEDRPV/xCAjJkEdTQYViQeducROHIkkN1LQ2r9Cifnus4B@4He5wXVTXbrApuTHABLMqjX1gHO/HWXxTrcoaT52hwYdGSDR960lwzSVWNjR0U1o@J8T5nVpL4GAPf58YOzvQoLOsYAs05D/la9hsdxf2KqHykdCTHUD0y5BcAL46cJk@)

Answer (score 1):

## shellutils, 26 bytes

A similar idea to the challenger's example

```
seq $1 $2|grep -o 1|wc -l
```

Explanation

`seq` prints all the numbers in the range given, increasing by `1` if not specified.

`grep -0 1` prints all `1` characters, one on each line

`wc -l` prints the number of lines

Answer (score 1):

### x86-32 assembly (26 bytes)

```
    xor    edi, edi       ; 31 FF     Set edi = 0 (counter for result)
    lea    esi, [edi+10]  ; 8D 77 0A  Set esi = 10
notFinished:
    mov    eax, ecx       ; 89 C8     eax contains the number to be checked next
notZero:
    xor    edx, edx       ; 31 D2
    div    esi            ; F7 F6     Separate digit from current number
    cmp    dl, 1          ; 80 FA 01  Check if this digit was one
    jne    notOne         ; 75 01
    inc    edi            ; 47        When the digit was one, increase counter
notOne:
    test   eax, eax       ; 85 C0
    jnz    notZero        ; 75 F2     Loop until all digits of current number are checked
    cmp    ebx, ecx       ; 39 CB
    loopnz notFinished    ; E0 EC     Loop until end of range is reached
    ret                   ; C3
```

[Online working example](http://tpcg.io/YWAVrLwR)

Intel syntax is used here. The opcodes are given in the middle column between the source code and the comments. The parameters are transferred in registers:

- `ebx` contains range start
- `ecx` contains range end

The result is returned in the `edi` register.

**Credit:** Thanks to [640KB](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84624/640kb) for pointing out that looping from high to low saves one byte here.

Comment: Very nice one! I think you can -1 byte by looping high to low and then using a `loopnz` instead of `inc` and `jb`. http://tpcg.io/geET58Ud.  However, for machine code callable functions, a `ret` is [required at the end](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/how-are-bytes-counted-in-assembly/12352#12352) (sorry), so that's +1 byte there.

Comment: Thanks, don't know about this meta post yet. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 73 bytes

```clj
(defn h[s e](count(filter #(= \1 %)(into[](apply str(range s(inc e)))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYtBCoMwEEX3PcWHUpjsjIXaTU@iLiQdqxImYRIXnj4Guip9y/f@dz5su3Ip9OZZsPQJPJILu2SaV59ZcaUXBouboVVy6EeaYvQHUlbSST6MVIMDmy@FotahF9ACC9s0xlx@nEX7L9s7Ht2z3k8)

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn how-many-ones [start end]
  (count (filter #(= \1 %) (into [] (apply str (range start (inc end)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 50 bytes

```swift
{($0...$1).flatMap{"\($0)".filter{$0=="1"}}.count}
```

Short explanation: Maps every number in the range to a string and filters every character which is equal to 1 and counts the resulting characters.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQZqXhmVeiA8SaunYgpqaC7f9qDRUDPT09FUNNvbScxBLfxIJqpRigmKaSXlpmTklqUbWKga2tkqFSba1ecn5pXknt/4KizLwSjTQNQx1DAwNNTS4431DHCFXAyFjHzNwCKPIfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `s`, 4 bytes

```
ṡƛ1O
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E1%B9%A1%C6%9B1O&inputs=100%0A1&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
ṡƛ1O;
ṡ       # Create an inclusive range between the two inputs
 ƛ      # For each item in that range:
  1O    #   Count the number of 1s
        # The 's' flag autosums t.o.s and implicitly prints.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ŸJ1¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6A4vw0OL/v83NDDgMgQA) Takes two lines of input, the first one being `b` and the second being `a`.

```
   ¢  # total number of
  1   # ones
   ¢  # in
 J    # joined elements of
Ÿ     # [a, ..., b]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
a->b->count("1",join(a:b))
```

expects `f(a)(b)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBbsIwEETv@Ypt6MGWDMZBohESSO2xx/ZIqeQ4m8Qo2Mg2iL9PN5CqUn2ynme8s3O89Far2/CmIy6Mv7jE9GbzWsUUtEmfKVjXCqj@Iw5b6NG1qWPG9z2axFCb7qST6dgHtnhjmpOPc57NwEaosbEO6/F68gEhoEGX4IohWu8i@Abexyik7lI6x42UtTdxcRxhr1278KGV6ORVyYqyymnsaJazv/RZ1lC0Qc931Xz32CdXuTh662gxyjMkjCmSZp8Bnb0SoJbLA2x3UCgxMYLFBNWq/KXFSsD6pXzgshDZgab5AIxpUXGBHKyD@/d3w5mKSv197OhoqBFGMsjp7Yv6up0pP1XyjDyHb2CTAJ62gFQbunr4AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 75 bytes

```
=SUM(LEN(SEQUENCE((F5-E5),,E5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SEQUENCE((F5-E5),,E5),1,"")))
```

Not very efficient, but works. Sequence generates a sequence of integers, and using the  length/substitute calculation the number of ones is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `SS`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Idḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1JZCVFMSVCOCU4NSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTElMEExMDAmZmxhZ3M9U1M=)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
IJ1c
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1JSjFjJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MSUwQTEwMCZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
Idḅ   # Implicit input    ->  1, 100
I     # Inclusive range   ->  [1..100]
 d    # Digits of each    ->  [[1],[2],...,[9,9],[1,0,0]]
  ḅ   # Check for == 1    ->  [[1],[0],...,[0,0],[1,0,0]]
      # Sum (flatten)     ->  [1,0,...0,0,1,0,0]
      # Sum the list      ->  21
      # Implicit output
```

```python
IJ1c  # Implicit input    ->  1, 100
I     # Inclusive range   ->  [1..100]
 J    # Join into string  ->  "123...99100"
  1c  # Count 1s          ->  21
      # Implicit output
```